# Что займет времени больше: переформатирование исходного DataFrame или создание нового?

Tags: python, pandas

интересует такой вопрос. Есть один большой DataFrame, который мне нужно преобразовать и сохранить. Что будет оптимальнее по времени:

1. Переделать уже исходный DataFrame, а ненужную часть отбросить при помощи `pd.drop()`
2. Создать новый DataFrame на основе уже преобразованных данных

Comment: Почему бы вам не сделать пару тестов и сравнить обе варианты между собой?

Comment: Сильно зависит от многих параметров, это только пробовать.

Comment: Без понимания того, что вы хотите получить и того как выглядит входной фрейм, невозможно дать вразумительный ответ. Каким бы ни был плохим код, всегда можно написать хуже и чтобы он ещё медленнее работал ;)